# Программа не хочет работать с переменными TextField

Tags: java, javafx, gui, scene-builder

Есть программа, выполненная в javafx:

```
package sample;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;

import javax.script.ScriptException;
import java.awt.*;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private TextField dni;

    @FXML
    private TextField num;

    @FXML
    private TextField minRes;

    @FXML
    private TextField maxRes;



    @FXML
    private void process(ActionEvent event) throws ScriptException {

        double d = Double.parseDouble(dni.getText());
        double s = 8;
        double e = 1;
        double k = 2;
        double y = 1;
        double n = 0.83;
        double r = 2;
        double Vr = (24-s-e-k-y-n-r)*d; //время на работу без учёта отдыха

        double pod=25;
        double kolpod=4;

        double p = Double.parseDouble(num.getText());

        if (p==2){
            pod = 30;
            kolpod =5;
        }
        if (p==3){
            pod = 35;
            kolpod =6;
        }
        if (p==4){
            pod = 40;
            kolpod =7;
        }
        if (p==5){
            pod = 45;
            kolpod =8;
        }
        if (p==6){
            pod = 50;
            kolpod =9;
        }
        if (p==7){
            pod = 55;
            kolpod =10;
        }

        double Srp=pod*kolpod; //время работы в цикле
        double So = 5*kolpod+20; //время отдыха в цикле
        double Vobsh = Srp+So; // время одного цикла с учётом работы и отдыха
        Vr=Vr-5;//С учётом времени на общение
        double Rrv = Vr/Vobsh*Srp; //Реальное времяф работы

        minRes.setText(String.valueOf(Rrv));

        k = 1;
        y = 0.5;
        r = 1;

        Vr = (24-s-e-k-y-n-r)*d; //время на работу без учёта отдыха
        Srp=pod*kolpod; //время работы в цикле
        So = 5*kolpod+20; //время отдыха в цикле

        Vobsh = Srp+So; // время одного цикла с учётом работы и отдыха

        Vr=Vr-5;//С учётом времени на общение

        Rrv = Vr/Vobsh*Srp; //Реальное время работы

        maxRes.setText(String.valueOf(Rrv));
    }
}
```

Но почему-то в коде, отвечающем за графический интерфейс (картинка ниже), имена переменных, отвечающих за связь с текстовыми панелями, выделяются красным
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в том, что `TextField` у вас заимпорчено из `java.awt` пакета, а надо из `javafx.scene.control.`